# Generate Pdf, excel from SSRS HTML 4.0 report format

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, ssrs-2012

We have developed web application in MVC 5.0. We are using SQL Server Reporting Services and we are render report without using reportviewer we render it into HTML 4.0 format.

Now  we want to generate  this SSRS report output into pdf and excel format on button click of pdf and excel. How can we do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "URL Access Parameters" that are built into SSRS to generate the report in the appropriate format.

See documentation here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152835(v=sql.110).aspx
https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2016/07/01/integrating-sql-server.aspx

Build the URL to the report using the '**&rs:Format**' parameter and hook that up to your corresponding buttons.